# Android AVD Emulator, how to simulate bad and slow devices/ simulate real devices and their performance

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

how can I force an AVD emulator to run slower/ match the speed of a specific older/ slower phone? I am trying to experiment how my app will run on slower devices but I the emulators are too fast for that. I am using Android Studio and AVD.